# Prediction of Words from the corpus

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to build a model where, as the user types, my model should predict the word (Name of a medicine in this case). I have a corpus of all the words that are going to be typed. When I tried to use rnn with lstm to predict these words, I'm getting words that are similar to the words present in the corpus, but not the actual words.

For Example:
The user types: flu

Expected Output: fluvoxamine

What I'm Getting: {'re','cobact','nate','diclox','te-cv'}

which are simlar to many names present in the corpus of medicines, but none exist in the name of 'flure', 'flucobact', ....

Where am I going wrong and what changes should I make to get the desired output.
The code I'm using to do this is:

```
# Setup
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from numpy.core.multiarray import dtype
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dropout
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout, RepeatVector
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use('agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle
import sys
import heapq
import seaborn as sns
from pylab import rcParams

np.random.seed(42)
tf.set_random_seed(42)

sns.set(style='whitegrid', palette='muted', font_scale=1.5)
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 12, 5

# Loading the data
# path = 'nietzsche.txt'
# path = 'nietzschemod.txt'
path = 'BrandedProductNames.txt'
text = open(path).read().lower()
print ('Corpus length: ', len(text))

# Preprocessing
# Finding all the unique characters in the corpus
chars = sorted(list(set(text)))
char_indices = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(chars))
indices_char = dict((i, c) for i, c in enumerate(chars))

print ("unique chars: ", len(chars))

# Cutting the corpus into chunks of 40 chars, spacing the sequences by 3 characters
# We will additionally store the next character (the one we need to predict) for every sequence

SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 3
step = 3
sentences = []
next_chars = []
for i in range(0, len(text) - SEQUENCE_LENGTH, step):
    sentences.append(text[i:i + SEQUENCE_LENGTH])
    next_chars.append(text[i + SEQUENCE_LENGTH])
print ('num training examples: ', len(sentences))

# Generating features and labels.
# Using previously generated sequences and characters that need to be predicted to create one-hot encoded vectors

X = np.zeros((len(sentences), SEQUENCE_LENGTH, len(chars)), dtype=np.bool)
y = np.zeros((len(sentences), len(chars)), dtype=np.bool)
for i, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
    for t, char in enumerate(sentence):
        X[i, t, char_indices[char]] = 1
    y[i, char_indices[next_chars[i]]] = 1

# """
# Building the model

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(SEQUENCE_LENGTH, len(chars))))
model.add(Dense(len(chars)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

# Training
optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.01)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

# history = model.fit(X, y, validation_split=0.05, batch_size=128, epochs=20, shuffle=True).history
history = model.fit(X, y, validation_split=0.05, batch_size=128, epochs=1000, shuffle=True).history

# Saving
# model.save('keras_model'+str(SEQUENCE_LENGTH)+'.h5')
model.save('Med_keras_model' + str(SEQUENCE_LENGTH) + '.h5')
# pickle.dump(history, open('history'+str(SEQUENCE_LENGTH)+'.p', 'wb'))
pickle.dump(history, open('Med_history' + str(SEQUENCE_LENGTH) + '.p', 'wb'))
# """

# Loading back the saved weights and history

# model = load_model('keras_model'+str(SEQUENCE_LENGTH)+'.h5')
# history = pickle.load(open('history'+str(SEQUENCE_LENGTH)+'.p', 'rb'))
model = load_model('Med_keras_model' + str(SEQUENCE_LENGTH) + '.h5')
history = pickle.load(open('Med_history' + str(SEQUENCE_LENGTH) + '.p', 'rb'))

# Evaluation
plt.plot(history['acc'])
plt.plot(history['val_acc'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')

plt.show()
plt.savefig("01.Accuracy.png")

plt.plot(history['loss'])
plt.plot(history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')

plt.show()
plt.savefig("02.Loss.png")


# Testing
def prepare_input(text):
    x = np.zeros((1, SEQUENCE_LENGTH, len(chars)))
    for t, char in enumerate(text):
        x[0, t, char_indices[char]] = 1
    return x


# The sequences must be 40 chars long and the tensor is of the shape (1, 40, 57)


# The sample function
# This function allows us to ask our model what are the next probable characters (The heap simplifies the job)
def sample(preds, top_n=3):
    preds = np.asarray(preds).astype('float64')
    preds = np.log(preds)
    exp_preds = np.exp(preds)
    preds = exp_preds / np.sum(exp_preds)
    return heapq.nlargest(top_n, range(len(preds)), preds.take)


# Prediction function
def predict_completion(text):
    # print "From predict_completion: Text= "+text
    original_text = text
    completion = ''
    while True:
        x = prepare_input(text)
        preds = model.predict(x, verbose=0)[0]
        next_index = sample(preds, top_n=1)[0]
        next_char = indices_char[next_index]

        text = text[1:] + next_char
        # print ("From predict_completion: Text after appending= " + text)
        completion += next_char
        # print ("From predict_completion: completion= " + completion)
        # print (str(len(original_text + completion) + 2),str(len(original_text)), str(next_char == ' '), next_char)
        print (next_char)
        if len(original_text + completion) + 2 > len(original_text) and (
                next_char == ' ' or next_char == '\n' or next_char == '\r' or next_char == '\t'):
            return completion


# This methods wraps everything and allows us to predict multiple completions
def predict_completions(text, n=3):
    x = prepare_input(text)
    # print "Prepared input for "+text
    preds = model.predict(x, verbose=0)[0]
    # print "Prediction Done for "+text
    next_indices = sample(preds, n)
    # print "Created next indices "+text
    return [indices_char[idx] + predict_completion(text[1:] + indices_char[idx]) for idx in next_indices]


inputtxt = [
    "abacavir",
    "acemetacin",
    "dasatinib",
    "erythropoietin",
    "fluvoxamine"
]

for txt in inputtxt:
    seq = txt[:SEQUENCE_LENGTH].lower()
    print (seq)
    print (predict_completions(seq, 5))
    print ()
```